# how do i assemble bunch of excel files into one or more using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, api, bioinformatics

how to there is around 10k .csv files named as data0,data1 like that in sequence, want to combine them and want to have a master sheet in one file or at least couple of sheets using python because i think there is limitation of around 1070000 rows in one excel file i  think?

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

master_df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
  if file.endswith('.csv'):
    master_df = master_df.append(pd.read_csv(file))

master_df.to_csv('master file.CSV', index=False)
```

Comment: Pls format your code.

Comment: @DevangSanghani please review again

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note:

1. Please check your csv file content first. It would easily mismatch columns when reading csv with text(maybe ; in the content). Or you can try changing the csv engine

   df= pd.read_csv(csvfilename,sep=';', encoding='utf-8',engine='python')
2. If you want to combing into one sheet, your can concat into one dataframe first, then to_excel

   df = pd.concat([df,sh_tmp],axis=0,sort=False)

note: concat or append would be a straightforward way to combine data. However, 10k would lead to a perfomance topic. Try list instead of pd.concat if you facing perfomance issue.

3. Excel has maximum row limitation. 10k files would easily exceed the limit (1048576). You might change the output to csv file or split into multiple .xlsx

----update the 3rd----

You can try grouping the data first (1000k each), then write to sheet one by one.

```
row_limit = 1000000
master_df['group']=master_df.index//row_limit

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path_out)
for gr in range(0,master_df['group'].max()+1):
    master_df.loc[master_df['group']==gr].to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet'+str(gr),index=False)    
writer.save()
```

Comment: yeah your first point is correct, whats the solution for it?

Comment: your all points are valid specially 3rd, that's what the solution i want, i'm new into python, can you help?

Comment: I've update my answer for it

Comment: is it the full executable code?

Comment: You can append it to your code and try